# Substitution on integral

Tags: integration

I have this (it looks simple) example

$$\int \frac{3}{2-5x}\,dx$$

It looks really simple, no logarithms or trigonometric functions, but I just cannot get the proper result here...

Comment: Try: $t=2-5x. $

Comment: A right result is $-\frac{3}{5}\ln(|2-5x|)+C$. But there are equivalent ways to write it. What did you get?

Comment: set $u=2-5x$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
u & = 2 - 5x \\[15pt]
du & = -5\,dx \\[15pt]
-du/5 & = dx \\[15pt]
\int \frac{3}{2-5x}\,dx & = \int \frac{3}{u} \left(\frac{du}{-5}\right) \\[15pt]
& =\frac{-3}{5}\int \frac 1 u \, du \\[15pt]
& = \frac{-3}{5}\log_e |u| + C \\[15pt]
& = \frac{-3}{5}\log_e|2-5x| + C
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry --- typo.  It's an $e$.